# angular ng-show/hide depends on img src url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to do ng-show/hide an image base on the src url which is never going to be empty? I tried ng-show="ImageUrl!== ''/null" but that's not going to work because there url is always present, the img src is coming from the server side.

```
<img data-ng-src="{{ImageUrl}}" id="profile-picture_image" data-ng-show="ImageUrl" alt="Candidate profile photo" class="img-responsive img-rounded">

<img src="//@@websiteHost/Content/img/no-photo.png" alt="Candidate without profile photo" data-ng-show="!ImageUrl" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
```

Comment: If the image URL is never going to be empty, on which criteria should the showing/hiding be based?

Comment: Have you tried `data-ng-show="ImageUrl.length"` ?

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm asking if there's another way of doing it in UI point of view, otherwise I will have to ask the backend to give me something to be based on.

Comment: @DarthBatuKhan mind explaining why .length?

Comment: You can set flag which tells you the image is available or not and use ng-show="IsImageAvailable==1'"

Comment: @PrakashPanchal can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Try something below:

html :

```
ng-show="isImageAvailable(this)"
```

controller:

```
$scope.isImageAvailable = function(imageobj) {
    var imagename = imageobj.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    return !(imagename == "no-photo.png");
}
```

Or something like to explode the image name from image path:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src').split('/');
var file = src[src.length - 1];
```